# How to use same scripts in views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view for creating an entity by filling a form. That form contains several inputs and 2 datatables table. i write a considerable amount of JavaScript code for initialization and validation of the inputs. For editing the entity, i need the 95% of inputs and JavaScript codes.

**First**, I tried to move the common codes to a partial view but some of them worked and some of it didn't work. For example the tables not initialized.

As a **second** approach, I can also  write a lot of if-else to check the current page (between Create and Edit) and do proper action.

How can i have two views and common codes in both? Is there a better or functional approach?

Comment: Scripts should never be in partials (only the view or its layout)

Comment: @StephenMuecke then what is the solution? I don't want to copy paste all the scripts in the views

Comment: Put then in an external js file and include it in both views

Answer (score 0):

save your javascript code as js file. Drag  and drop its link where you want to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same view for Create and edit functionality.
And regarding the inputs, you can take one property in the model which will indicate whether to show or not to show that input on UI.

Model:
For eg. Public string displayInput=[none/block]
view:

You need to set the value of displayInput field properly when you want to show all fields and when you want to hide some fields.